# implementing Magento EAV with proper grid & forms in admin panel

Tags: magento, entity-attribute-value, adminhtml

I am trying to implement an EAV CRUD module in magento. My module name is Pincodes.
It should be just like the Attribute Management under Admin panel >> Catalog >> Attributes >> Manage Attribute

So far I have implemented the whole module by following the Module Adminhtml >> catalog >> product >> Attributes

I am having few issues.

1. My table eavpincodes does not have any column like `attribute_id`. So while preparing collection I get an SQL error of unknown column. But `catalog_eav_Attribute` has that column. I only have few tables eavpincodes eavpincodes_datatime, eavpincodes_int etc. These tables are automatically generated by magento
2. Something is wrong about code that I am not able to identify when I go to create new attribute it renders the whole layout but no form appears. Moreover there is no error, no exception not even a single error of file inclusion.

Here is a link to my code. I don't know its going to make any sense to u or not but any help is much appreciated.

[Pincode - download here](http://hotfile.com/dl/112342786/d0aade1/Pincodes.zip.html)